# How to make a function find and print list of words with a specific rules in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, count

I want to make function that can find words with specific rule 
for example :

```
 count_words( word_list, [["a", 2], ["e", 3]] )
```

I want to find the words have 2 'a's and 3 'e's from word list 
and How can I change the rule every time I want to test the function

Comment: What code have you written so far and what problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_words(word_list, input_tuple):
    return [word for word in word_list if word.count(input_tuple[0]) >= input_tuple[1]]
```

where input_tuple has the format ('a', 2)

Comment: Simply use `word.count`, there's no need to convert it to a list. This doesn't answer the OP's question : what about his two (or more) conditions: `[["a", 2], ["e", 3]]`?

Comment: The question doesnt ask about two or more conditions, it asks how to "change the rule every time I want to test the function" which I interpreted to mean that he simply wants to run the function number of times with different arguments. its not terribly clear.

Comment: Note that there may be an arbitrary number of specifications such as the
   above. For example,

      count_words_v1( word_list, [["a", 1], ["ee", 1], ["t", 1]] )

   should return all words with a single occurrence of letters "a" and "t," as
   well as substring "ee." For example, the word "trainees" satisfies the above
   specification.

  function should include a word from the input word list in the return value of
   count_words_v1() if and only iff that word satisfies ALL given specifications.